# Posterous Theming Image hover box

Tags: html, css, image, theming, posterous

Within posterous when you hover on an image it displays a box enabling the user to download or view the full size image. Here is the example of how this should work.

[image]

I am trying to find out why this does not work in the theme I created [Here](http://dave.radparvar.com/awesome-photos-by-gokateshoot-from-a-great-br). Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a quick look at your code. The span that's supposed to show up; 1 has no id associated with it and two is not showing when you hover over the image. Make sure your javsacript is correct. I think it is most likely being referenced wrong.

```
    <span id="" class="show">
        <div id="-dl3" style="font-size: 14px; position: absolute; right: 10px; bottom: 0px;">
        <div id="-dl2" class="posterousGalleryLink" style="font-size: 14px; display: none;">Download this gallery (ZIP, null KB)</div>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/jCcnC/

Comment: Thank you so much for this, so sorry I forgot to mention that I have no control of the javascript within a posterous theme.